# How to swap 2 values in a dictionary, given the 3rd's key?

Tags: python, dictionary, swap

Suppose that I have dictionary with 3 keys `'x'`, `'y'` and `'z'`. What I need to do is to write a function that, given `'x'` as argument, swaps the values stored in `'y'` and `'z'`.

```
def swap(d, key):
    a, b = [_ for _ in d if _ != key]
    d[a], d[b] = d[b], d[a]
```

This is what I've came up with, but I'm looking for a more simple and concise way. Is there any, as far as you know?

Comment: Your existing code seems good to me. It could definitely use some better name choices, but other than that, it's simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What names do you suggest?

Comment: `_` is definitely a bad choice. It implies that you're discarding the value. I'd suggest changing it, but ShadowRanger's suggestion lets you get rid of the variable entirely. `swap` suggests a commutative operation that swaps its arguments, and `key` could be more informative about how it's the unaffected key, but the best replacement choices would depend heavily on the context in which you're using this function. It seems like your context probably has a meaningful name for this operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a slightly more clever means of determining the keys to swap by doing:

```
a, b = d.keys() - {key}  # On Py3; on Python 2.7, you'd use d.viewkeys()
```

but it's a pretty minor "improvement"; using `set` operations moves more work to the C layer, avoiding the Python layer iteration of a `list` comprehension, but the difference when you're talking about iterating three values is pretty trivial.

It's using a [`KeysView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.KeysView) (a live, `set`-like view of the `dict`'s keys) to get `set` operations to preserve the two keys not passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this this way, to avoid using loop:

```
def swap(dictS, key):
    keys = list(dictS.keys())
    keys.remove(key)
    dictS[keys[0]], dict[keys[1]] = dictS[keys[1]], dict[keys[0]]
```

Comment: This involves repeated lookups to get the values; sequence unpacking is a good thing, and should be used when appropriate to avoid repeated lookups of the same values; [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, we first need to find the two keys that are not same as the input key. We then just swap the values for those keys.

```
def swap(d, key):
   keys_to_swap = []
   for k in d:
       if k != key:
           keys_to_swap.append(k)
   # keys_to_swap are the keys that need to be swapped
   # Swap now
   temp = d.get(keys_to_swap[0])
   d[keys_to_swap[0]] = d.get(keys_to_swap[1])
   d[keys_to_swap[1]] = temp
   return d
```

Your original answer is correct, but you are not returning d.
So to correct your solution:

```
def swap2(d, key):
    a, b = [_ for _ in d if _ != key]
    d[a], d[b] = d[b], d[a]
    return d #Added this line
```

Comment: This isn't really an improvement over what the questioner already has.

Comment: I don't want the function to return `d`. It just needs to swap the values.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Sorry!